# Powershell Xml -> Recurse

Tags: xml, powershell

is there any recurse function which will parse whole Xml wchich structure will be something like this:

```
<main>
 <object>
  <otherObject>
   VALUE
  </otherObject>
 </object>
</main>
```

The problem is that i will don't know how many object will be there and how many child will be under parents. The last child (which don't has child) will have VALUE like in example.
Is there some built-in function, or do you have idea how to do it?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did sth like this:

```
unction GetChilds{
param(
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xmlContent,
[string]$path
)


$childs = $xmlContent.SelectNodes($path)

if(! ($childs.HasChildNodes))
    {
    $path = $path.Remove($path.Length-2,2)

    $value = $xmlContent.SelectSingleNode($path).InnerText.Trim()

    }

if(($childs.HasChildNodes))
    {
    foreach($child in $childs)
    {
        $childName = $child.LocalName

        $newpath = $path.TrimEnd('*')
        $newpath = $newpath + $childname

        $newpath=$newpath + "/*"
        GetChilds $xmlContent $newPath
    }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read your file with `$xmlContents = [xml](get-content "filename.xml")`